GitHub Action uploading artifacts -fails to see files
I'm having an issue trying to upload artifacts from cypress (e2e) tests in a GitHub Action. Where the issue is likely because I'm not clear on the GitHub Action syntax.
name: Test cypress action


on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:
  pull_request:
    types: ["opened", "edited", "reopened", "synchronize", "ready_for_review"]

jobs:
  fail_if_pull_request_is_draft:
    if: github.event.pull_request.draft == true
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Fails in order to indicate that pull request needs to be marked as ready to review
        run: exit 1

  ci:
    name:  Build, lint, test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.event.pull_request.draft == false
    timeout-minutes: 30
    services:
      edgedb:
        image: edgedb/edgedb:4
        env:
          EDGEDB_SERVER_SECURITY: insecure_dev_mode
        ports:
          - 5656:5656
    steps:
      - name: ⬇️ Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: ⎔ Setup node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          cache: npm
          cache-dependency-path: ./package-lock.json
          node-version: 18

      - name:  Install deps
        run: npm ci

      - name:  Lint
        run: npm run lint

      - name:  Install EdgeDB
        uses: edgedb/setup-edgedb@v1
        with:
          server-dsn: edgedb://localhost:5656
          instance-name: ci_edgedb_instance

      # Don't need migration as setup above does it
      - name:  Generate EdgeQL client
        run: npm run db:migrate

      - name:  Type check
        run: npm run typecheck

      - name:  Copy test env vars
        run: cp .env.example .en

      - name:  Seed the database
        run: npm run seed

      - name:  Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v6

        with:
          start: npm run dev
          wait-on: "http://localhost:5173"
          record: true

      - name: Archive screenshots
        if: failure()
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: screenshots
          path: ./cypress/screenshots

      - name: Archive videos
        if: always()
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: cypress-videos
          path: ./cypress/videos

The syntax in the cypress example (https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action?tab=readme-ov-file#artifacts) for uploading artifacts seems to have a very different structure where it doesn't separate steps by name... so I'm sure if that's out of date syntax.  Attempting to put the uses: for the artefact action within the Cypress run step just give an error. And running it as it is I just get a warning Warning: No files were found with the provided path: ./cypress/videos. No artifacts will be uploaded. Presumably as the step is separate to the cypress step and can't see the artificers??
